# No frills form submission

Tags: html, forms, checkbox

Being a moron in the ways of HTML I have been just messing around with trial and error with a little help from w3 schools.  I am trying to interface with what appears to be a CGI script and putting together a URL that sends all the information to the server.  I have gathered that this needs to be done with a form, and have most of the information I need except for multiple entries. 
example:

```
<form name="send" action="url" method="get" target="_blank">
       <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="lorem"/>
       <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="ipsum"/>
       <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

From my understanding and what I can piece together, if both check boxes are ticked it will generate a url.        `url?foo=lorem&foo=ipsum`
what I want it to output is a url like      "url?foo=lorem,ipsum"
Is this something that can be achieved with simple code?    Java & HTML only, don't want add in PHP or some other server side scripting language, mostly something that the browser can do all the work.

Comment: Why are you overwriting the same parameter with more than one value?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done using jQuery.

1. Install the jQuery library by adding a link tag to it in your head tags.
2. Get the value of each check box, and use if/else statements.

---

```
<script>
    var var1 = $('#box1').val();
    var var2 = $('#box2').val();
    var link1 = null;
    var link2 = null;
    if (var1 == null){}else{link1 = "lorem";};
    if (var2 == null){}else{link2 = "ipsum";};
</script>
```

Then just concatenate your link variables to a string exactly as you would like to.

For the above to work, you would have to set id="box1" and id="box2" on your input tags.

Comment: Okay I see how that picks up the input but you lost me at the concatenate part, do I tuck that into; `<input type="hidden" name="varstring" value="$var1,$var2">`

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve. I feel there is a much better way to do what you're trying to do. If you wanted to do it this way, you would have to create a long string which concatenates the URL characters such as ? and & to your variables, then submit it as a hidden field like in your comment above.

Comment: So, for purposes of the form, I have edited the code. 
`<form name="send" action="url" method="get" target="_blank">
 <input type="checkbox" ID="box1"/>
 <input type="checkbox" ID="box2"/>
 <Script>
  var var1 = $('#box1').val();
  var var2 = $('#box2').val();
  var link1 = null;
  var link2 = null;
  if (var1 == null){}else{link1 = "lorem";};
  if (var2 == null){}else{link2 = "ipsum";};
  var foo = link1,link2;
 </script>
 
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>`
so on button press I should get output url of 
`url?foo=lorem,ipsum`

Comment: No, all the JS is doing is creating two variables named link1 and link2 which have either the value NULL (if box isnt checked) or lorem/ipsum (if the relevant box is checked). You then need to use these variables to create whatever string you want, and assign it to your hidden field. Whatever your string ends up being, the value you send via $_GET will be ?foo=<WHATEVER YOU MADE IT>. For example if you just concatenated the two with an asterisk, it would be ?foo=lorem*ipsum

Comment: I don't know what you'll be doing with your submission, but parsing it down the road (Decoding it) will be very difficult if you do it this way.

Comment: Okay I think I see what I need to do now.  My problem at this point is syntax.  Information within the script tags just gets the information into a separate variable that I can mess with and then put together to form the variable to build the url for the Get method.  so at the end of the script to concatenate it I need a line `var finalstring = link1,link2;` finalstring being what I call from the form entry, what I am losing here is how to get that variable into `<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="[java_variable]">`  so when I click the submit button I get the url: url?foo=lorem,ipsum

Comment: All you need to do, once you have assigned "finalstring" to whatever you want it to be is use the .val again. So give your hidden field an id of "xyz" and... ('#xyz').val(finalstring); Then submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, another way you can do this is with jQuery's serialize.

It will take any elements you desire (i.e. all of the checkboxes in your form) and serialize them into a string (including their names and values), and you can parse (decode) them later.

```
$('#formSubmit').on("click", initEntrySubmission); //when the form's submit button is clicked, initiate the function "initEntrySubmission"

function initEntrySubmission(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  //prevent the form from immediately submitting
        var serializedInputs = $("#protocolForm :input").serialize(); //serialize the input fields in your form with id="protocolForm", and assign its value to a variable serializedInputs
        $('#serialInput').val(serializedProtocol); //your hidden form named serialInput
        $('form#entryForm').submit(); //submit the form after everything is done
    }
```

Ultimately though, your name="..." parameters should be different between check boxes or you will run into many problems downstream.